# Weird issue when try to create Jax-Rs 2.0 project on Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6

Tags: websphere, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

Can't understand what's wrong, but created Dynamic Web Project with the following facets:

1. Dynamic Web Module 3.1
2. Java 1.8
3. JavaScript 1.0
4. Jax-RS 2.0

**Runtime**: Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile.

It isn't my first project with such configuration and everything gone ok until now. In this project I receive the following error when try to perform any RESTful request:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] in application [EscapeRoom]: javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one provider or resource class should be specified for application class "javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.doInit(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:303)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one provider or resource class should be specified for application class "javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.doInit(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:303)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] in application [EscapeRoom]: javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one provider or resource class should be specified for application class "javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.doInit(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:303)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one provider or resource class should be specified for application class "javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4898)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: At least one provider or resource class should be specified for application class "javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.doInit(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:303)
    ... 1 more
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>EscapeRoom</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My jax-rs class:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestGet  {

    @GET
    public String getTest(){
        return "OK!";
    }

}
```

Pretty simple.

Tried to create the another project at the same workspace and it works fine.

Actually I can just copy all my frontend stuff from one project to another, but I don't like this workaround and would like to find the reason why it doesn't work, I think that I miss something obviously.

Comment: Based on the spec, this _should_ work. Try another option. Create an `Application` subclass, overriding `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()`, and return a set the with the `TestGet` class. For the servlet-name, instead of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, use the fully qualified name of the `Application` subclass. Like I said your current configuration _should_ work. This is just a test to see if other configuration options work.

Comment: I've found it, I guess it was caused by wrong `git` configuration. There were few folders in `web-inf` which didn't suppose to be there, `bin\...` I have deleted them and it begun to work. I need to complete my project ASAP because my deadline is tomorrow and then I will try to post a detailed response what did happen.